# Trying to use BigInt in typescript but it errors out even if ES2020 is the target in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

Currently getting a "BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ES2020." when I try to run my code.

I am trying to input a value of 9999999999999999, since it changes to 10000000000000000.

My code looks like this:

```
interface ShopItemPrice {
  readonly Type: 'item_price';
  Item: {
   Threshold: BigInt,
   Type: string,
  };
}
```

In a separate .ts file, this is how it looks like

```
blankActualBudget(): ShopItem<ShopItemPrice> {
  return {
    Type: 'item_price',
    Name: '',
    Metadata: {
      Threshold: 0n,
      SaleType: '',
    },
  };
}
```

The above code also points to `n` after the 0 as an immediate identifier.

My tsconfig.json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib":["ES2020.BigInt", "ESNext", "ES2020"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My typescript version is 3.9.9, so I'm not sure what's happening. Any idea as to what's the cause of this?

Comment: The typescript primitive type for BigInt is `bigint` in all lowercase

Comment: Thanks for that! I've already changed it, but I'm still getting the `BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ES2020.` error.

Comment: Hmm. Let me set up a typescript project on my machine and try

Comment: I created a new npm project and installed `typescript@3.9.9` and added a script to package.json to run the locally installed `tsc` (`scripts: {"tsc": "tsc"}`), and it works for me. Is your code compiling possibly with a globally installed `tsc` that is a different version?

Comment: Are you running `tsc` on a single file? If you do, `tsconfig.json` gets ignored, and it's a very common confusion.

Comment: I was. However upon adding a 2nd file with the function and importing the interface in there and running "npm run tsc" again, it still works. If I change the target to "ES2017" then I get the same error as @johnnyrocket33

Comment: How do I know if the globally installed `tsc` is a different version? My `package.json` tsc is `typescript": "^3.5.3`, which should be able to run BigInt, right?

Comment: But yes, I do think my `tsconfig.json` is getting ignored, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Update: It seems to accept `bigint` now, but the value still changes from 9999999999999999 to 10000000000000000 on the field when I input it. It does this automatically.